# Wordpress update post optimize

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Background**

I'm have a cron job that runs every 24hours, which goes thru every post for a specifik post type and update the post with new data that is collected from an api. At this point it is working. But that is only because there is only about 1500 posts. But I know that this is gonna increase to about 40000-80000 posts.

And currently it takes about 20 min to run the update (mainly because the api has a request limit to 30 calls/min). So the that I can't do anything about. And it is gonna take longer the more posts I get in the database.

I'm also using ACF pro to add fields to the post type.

But what i'm worried about is that the database will get errors because the sql calls is to heavy and to many.

**How it looks today**

The current setup is like this:

- Server 1: Webserver
- Server 2: Mysql server

And the update code currently looks like this, and I feel like it must be some better way to do this.

```
public function updatePosts($apiPosts){

  /** Loop thru every post from the api, these are setup in another function */
  foreach($apiPosts as $post){
  /** Look to see if a post exist with the code */
     $args = [
       'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
       'meta_key'  => 'code',
       'meta_value' => $post->code,
       'posts_per_page' => 1
     ];
     $post = get_posts($args);

     /** If no post was found, create a new post */
     if(!$post[0]){
       $newPost = [
          'post_title' => $post->title,
          'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
          'post_status' => 'publish'
       ]
       $post_id = wp_insert_post($newPost);
     }else{
       $post_id = $post[0]->ID
     }

     /** Update the acf fields on the post */
     update_field('field1', $post->field1, $post_id);
     update_field('field2', $post->field2, $post_id);
     update_field('field3', $post->field3, $post_id);
     update_field('field4', $post->field4, $post_id);
     update_field('field5', $post->field5, $post_id);
     update_field('field6', $post->field6, $post_id);
     update_field('field7', $post->field7, $post_id);
  }
}
```

I'm open to all suggestions that you have. I have a feeling that is need to optimize this. because in that loop, it can easy be 40000 posts to loop thru as I mention before.

Comment: This is missing a `'` and the syntax went off the rails.

Comment: thanks for pointing that one out, I have fixed that now

Answer (score 1):

I would split this data to smaller parts, like:

1. Store api data separately (Somewhere in options table)
2. set an update action to run more often, WP suppest to use a limit maximum every 10 minutes, but it will work even with one minute timeout (You'll need to adjust `cron_scheldules` however)
3. Replace get_posts with a query to db that look in postmeta table and return only post ID if found.
4. Run it for a specific amuout of posts. Once post check performed (from api) performed remove post from api queue.
5. Once update is done (lets say for 50 posts), Update  API queue.
6. I assume, that updates will not always update posts (like information didn't changed), find a way to check this before running update, you can remove from queue all posts that not going to be udpated (so less work for your update action).

UPDATE

7. You also can  populate custom fields info one fiels and store ther array (which you will later unserialize and use on a front end). Only this action will decrease sql queries (and cache drops) number by 7 queries.

   `update_post_meta($ID, '_global_meta', $array_of_updated_data);`

Comment: On point 7, that is not possible because the admins of the websites need to see the information in the admin section of the post type in a structure way. That is why I have used ACF.
But I will look int other points you listed up  :)

Comment: Hm,  I would check ACF on how meta data request from DB one by one or all on one request, and based on this information I would play with meta table filter (one that filter data requested from meta table). So in the backend for plugin, you will see a correct way information (like it has several separate rows), which in reality will be stored as 1 filed. Checkout `get_metadata` for filter name and additional meta hooks (like update)

Comment: Well i'm currently working on rebuild on it will works on the points that you have pointed out. And hopefully it will be a little better :)